# Connecting html pages to vue page

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

i created a dashboard using vue.js  but i have earlier created simple web pages using basic Html and CSS . Is there any method of redirecting the Html page to vue dashboard on click of a button .
Vue dashboard is a different project

Answer (score 3):

It is better and easier to just transform the static HTML page into a component by simply creating a component and copy pasting the static HTML code inside the component `template` however if you insist on importing the file as HTML format you might need to install a package called [html-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader) with :

```
yarn add html-loader | npm install html-loader
```

Then you need to update your `webpack.config.js` file with :

```
{
   test: /\.(html)$/,
   exclude: /(node_modules)/,
   use: {
   oader: "html-loader"
   }
}
```

Then you import the HTML file with :

```js
 import FileName from '/path/to/yourFilePath.html'
```

And finally you nest the template inside your router config  :

```js
 {
  path: '/path',
  name: 'routeName',
  component: { template: FileName}
}
```